# How can i retrieve a post based on condition and edit the post specific to the user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using devise as authentication system and after user logged in i want to display a drop-down list where the user has to select a project name and click on next which should allow him  to view the posts that has been posted related to that project. The post can be posted and viewed by many user whereas the user should be able to edit only the posts that he has posted but can view all the posts. How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you gone through any role based modeling,you can try [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan),or for your simple use case you have owner or belongs_to relation ship with user.

So you can use before filter while editing post if user is owner of post or not

```
before_filter :is_owner_of_post,:only=>[:edit,:update,:destroy]
protected
def is_owner_of_post
 @post = Post.find(params[:id])
 if @post.user != current_user
  redirect_to root_path,:notice=>"Un authorized access"
 end 
end
```

Read some article or watch some [video](http://railscasts.com/?tag_id=26) regarding authorization you can get more idea.